# The dart implementation behind String.hashCode for use in other language

Tags: flutter, dart, hashcode

I mistakenly depended on String.hashCode's value in a flutter app and stored it in a server side. Now I want to be able to calculate a hash code of a string in nodeJS and get the same result as dart...

How can I achieve it? Didn't find the actual implementation of the String.hashCode in dart.

Answer (score 0):

The vm implementation of `String.hashCode` can be found in the sdk repo on github (https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk):

Example:

- StringHasher in [runtime/vm/object.cc](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/d7c944b4c05479b879777afebb4f35d9d8aaeeef/runtime/vm/object.cc#L19369)
- CombineHashes/FinalizeHash in [runtime/vm/hash.h](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/a2de29095e24496d29576bdc3e9bae9855d9f68a/runtime/vm/hash.h#L10)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Swift implementation that should return the same hashCode value for a simple String in iOS and Flutter:

```
extension String {
  func hashCode() -> UInt32 {
    var hash: UInt32 = 0
    for i in unicodeScalars.filter({ $0.isASCII }).map({ $0.value }) {
      hash = hash &+ i
      hash = hash &+ (hash << 10)
      hash = hash ^ (hash >> 6)
    }
    hash = hash &+ (hash << 3)
    hash = hash ^ (hash >> 11)
    hash = hash &+ (hash << 15)
    hash = hash & ((1 << 30) &- 1)
    return (hash == 0) ? 1 : hash
  }
}
```